# Ignore the Envelope and Body in the SOAP XML parameter in WEB API (.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on a Web API (.NET CORE 2.0), the API receives a SOAP based XML request. see below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns="http://example.com/ns">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:Customer>
       <ns:Id>123</ns:Id>
       <ns:Name>John Brown</ns:Name>
      </ns:Customer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above XML works fine, and accepted by the web api.

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/Customer")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        [Route("Detail")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Detail([FromBody]Envelope request)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Request Object:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Customer", Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Id", Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", Namespace = "http://example.com/ns")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The above code works fine, I would like to ask is there a better way to eliminate or remove the `Envelope` and `Body` class (decorated by XmlRoot and XmlElement)

So we only accepts the objects that we wanted.
It always requires me to create the Envelope and Body class everytime I create an object parameter just only to satisfy the SOAP xml.

Controller would be look like this.

```
[Route("api/Customer")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [Route("Detail")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Detail([FromBody]Customer request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

but still accepts the above XML.

Comment: The appropriate framework to create SOAP web services is WCF, not MVC. If you intend to emulate a SOAP service with MVC/Web API, you'll have to parse the header and body yourself. You *can't* discard them because they *do* contain important information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, we are migrating our code to dotnet core, and still the request is xml. And the above works on our end, but my question is there is a better way? (but using web api dotnet core). Thanks

Comment: SOAP is *not* XML. It's a very specific protocol with VERY specific expectations from the server. The envelope contains a *lot* more than namespaces, which means that what you posted here is invalid. You can't just ignore the header or body. If you want to simply create a REST API that accepts XML requests you don't have to do anything - Web API works with both XML and Json depending on the requests's `content-type`

Comment: To put it another way, nobody will be able to work with this quasi-SOAP controller, except your own code or people that write explicitly for it. It would be better to simply use the controller as-is and let *it* deserialize json/xml depending on the requests's `accept` and `content-type` headers, as it should

Comment: [Configuring Formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting#configuring-formatters) shows how to add the XML serializer to MVC's configuration. You'll have to add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml package